# How do I include the less version of bootstrap in my node project (local)?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less, gruntjs

I am trying to learn a little about node. I have successfully set up a node static web server and I want to get bootstrap going. I want to use Less only for my node project.

I was thinking I should do this but not sure if there is a better way?

1) download all the .less bootstrap files and install them in my /css folder
2) use grunt to compile all my less into .css files and then just link to the css files.

I have two questions...

1) will this process work?
2) is there a better way to work if this doesn't work?

Comment: i'm a fan of mincer, which has `less` support https://github.com/nodeca/mincer#serving-assets-over-http, and use bower http://bower.io/ to get bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this using `Grunt`, and I think it would work really well. I haven't come across a more automated way of running tasks, and use `Grunt` on several repositories (i.e. https://github.com/dreamyguy). One could use `Gulp` too, but `Grunt` is way more mature at the point of this writing.

You would have to setup `Grunt`, install [grunt-contrib-less](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less) and [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) to watch your files. Your `Gruntfile.js` would look something similar to this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Main project configuration
    grunt.initConfig({
        // Read NPM package information
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON("package.json"),
        // Compile CSS files from LESS
        less: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                    paths: ["src/css"]
                },
                files: {
                    // destination         // source
                    "src/css/result1.css": "app/less/source1.less",
                    "src/css/result2.css": "app/less/source2.less",
                    "src/css/result3.css": "app/less/source3.less"
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    paths: ["src/css"],
                    cleancss: true,
                    modifyVars: {
                        imgPath: "'http://mycdn.com/path/to/images'",
                        bgColor: "red"
                    }
                },
                files: {
                    "src/css/result1.css": "app/less/source1.less",
                    "src/css/result2.css": "app/less/source2.less"
                }
            }
        }
        // Watcher
        watch: {
            css: {
                files: "app/less/**/*.less",
                tasks: ["less:dev"]
            }
        }

    });

    // Load the grunt tasks
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-less");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-watch");

    // Compile production files
    grunt.registerTask("dist", [
        "less:dist"
    ]);

    // Compile developer friendly environment
    grunt.registerTask("dev", [
        "less:dev"
    ]);

    // Default task(s).
    grunt.registerTask("default", "dist");

};
```

You would of course have to modify the above to reflect your paths.

You can use wildcards anywhere, as I used on `app/less/**/*.less`. This example will scan for all files with `.less` extensions under the folder `/less/` and all its subfolders. Just note that when including wildcards on tasks like `less` or `sass` the files will be compiled alphabetically, and you still have to define the destination file, like so:

```
// Compile CSS files from LESS
less: {
    dev: {
        options: {
            paths: ["src/css"]
        },
        files: {
            // several sources can be compiled into one destination, if one creates an array with the sources
            "src/css/result1.css": [
                "app/less/lib/**/*.less",
                "app/less/source1.less",
                "app/less/source3.less",
                "app/less/source7.less"
            ],
            // all files under 'bootstrap' folder and subfolders are compiled into one file
            "src/css/bootstrap.css": "app/less/bootstrap/**/*.less"
        }
    },
    dist: {
        options: {
            paths: ["src/css"],
            cleancss: true,
            modifyVars: {
                imgPath: "'http://mycdn.com/path/to/images'",
                bgColor: "red"
            }
        },
        files: {
            "src/css/result1.css": "app/less/source1.less",
            "src/css/result2.css": "app/less/source2.less"
        }
    }
}
```

Be careful when using wildcards on this task, because the cascading effect of `CSS` might create undesired overrides.

Comment: thanks mate, do you know if I can use a wildcard on those file refs so that it will 'suck' up all the files in my css folder?

Comment: when I say do you know 'if' what I mean is do you know 'how'? is it 'css/*' sorry .net dev looking to convert :-)

Comment: When using `LESS`, you'll have to refer to the files being compiled to `CSS` with the `.less` extension, so you can use wildcards there. But the `CSS` file to which `LESS` is being compiled to won't take wildcards, because you'll have to be specific about it. See my updated reply. ;)

Comment: I'm glad I could help! I did some subtle corrections to the code, a misplaced comma, a missing comma and a wrongly named sub-task. But the whole config is still the same.